# PHP: Strange Array Behaviour After Object Type Casting to Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, php-5.6, php-7.2

When you do `array` type-casting of `json_decode`d value (with `$assoc = false`), PHP creates an array with string indices:

```
$a = (array)json_decode('{"7":"value1","8":"value2","9":"value3","13":"value4"}');

var_export($a);

//array (
//  '7' => 'value1',
//  '8' => 'value2',
//  '9' => 'value3',
//  '13' => 'value4',
//)
```

And for some reason these indices are not accessible:

```
var_dump(isset($a[7]), isset($a['7']));

//false
//false
```

When you try to create the same array by PHP itself, it is being created with numeric indices (string are automatically converted), and values are accessible using both strings and numbers:

```
$c = array('7' => 'value1', '8' => 'value2', '9' => 'value3','10' => 'value4');

var_export($c);

var_dump(isset($c[7]), isset($c['7']));

//array (
//  7 => 'value1',
//  8 => 'value2',
//  9 => 'value3',
//  13 => 'value4',
//)
//
//true
//true
```

Does anybody know what is going on here? Is it some bug of older PHP versions (the issue seems to be fixed on PHP version >= 7.2, but I can't find anything related in [changelog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.1))?

Here's the demo of what is going on: https://3v4l.org/da9CJ.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone please read the question carefully, it fails for older PHP versions (the second output tab on https://3v4l.org/)

Comment: Yeah I saw that, sorry. I guess you should be using the second param then and its fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be related to [bug #61655](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61655) fixed in 7.2.0:

> in a object property lookup by name always in string, but in array numeric 
>   string(like "22200" ) key will transform to numeric but not a string anymore.
>       when conversion internal HashTable did't changed so after conversion, key 
>   lookup will fail.

Clarified: `$a["2000"]` is always interpreted as `$a[2000]`, but `(array)` failed to cast object string keys to numbers. So the array contained string numeric indices, but the array syntax' automatic casting prevented those from being accessible.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks, I looked for something related to "json_decode", not for generic type-casting.

Comment: @GinoPane  i will recomend you to always use `true` when you need type casting. Check once my answer as two different version are working perfectly fine.

Comment: @AlivetoDie, thanks! Actually, I do use it (you can check my demo link and see the test-case with `true` passed). The reason for the question was, that I faced `json_decode` usage without second parameter and couldn't explain the magic with array indices.

Answer (score 0):

add `TRUE` to `json_decode()`

```
<?php
$a = json_decode('{"7":"value1","8":"value2","9":"value3","13":"value4"}',TRUE);

var_export($a);

var_dump(isset($a[7]), isset($a['7']));
```

https://3v4l.org/YuF9B

Answer (score 0):

add TRUE to json_decode() is possible, but it will couse to recode everything.

Becouse you have to change the access to the variables.

if your json look like this:

```
$return = '{"status":"ok","message":"","code":"200","data":{"1234":{"sid":1,"name":"foo"},"4321":{"sid":2,"name":"bar"}}}';
```

on:

```
$json_data = json_decode($return, true);
$data = $json_data['data'];
```

you can loop the $data and have to access the values as array:
$data[0]['name'] ...

on:

```
$json_data = json_decode($return);
$data = (array) $json_data->data;
```

you can loop the $data and have to access the values as objects:
$data[0]->name ...